# Have javascript make a list of all internal href=#'s on a page

Tags: javascript, html, dom, hyperlink, internal

Is there a way to have javascript make an array of all the internal href=#'s on a page?

The idea is to have a drop down menu that would contain links to all anchors on a page.

Comment: Is it your intention to load a code library to accomplish this? Or should we honor the tags you chose for your question?

Comment: `document.links` is tailor-made for this.

Comment: i was thinking straight javascript, since i have zero experience with jquery, but i might reconsider. basically, for now all i need is to have anything output the list of the anchors, either in an alert, or as document.write, or as anything, so that i can figure out what to do with it further

Comment: i have re-read people's comments, and realize that you were right, i don't actually have the href's. THIS is what I need the script for. I do have a bunch of <a name='blahblah'>'s

Comment: @unomyname: I updated my answer to get the names instead.

Comment: FYI: `document.anchors` covers anchor tags with `name` attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the browser support you need, you can do this:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName( 'a' );

var hashes = Array.prototype.map.call( elems, function( v, i ) {
    return v.hash;
}).filter( function( v, i, a ) { return !!v && a.indexOf( v ) === i; });
```

You can gain support for older browsers using the shims provided by MDN.

- [`map()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`filter()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`indexOf()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexof)

---

In your comment, you noted that you want the `name` instead of the `href`.

You can do this, and it brings greater browser support automatically, though you'll still want to get support for `indexOf()`.

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName( 'a' );

var names = [];

for( var i = 0, len = elems.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    if( elems[i].name && names.indexOf( elems[i].name ) === -1 ) {
        names.push( elems[i].name ); 
    }
}
```

Comment: `!!v && a.indexOf( v ) ==== i;` is black magic to me, Why would the `indexOf` check ever fail?

Comment: @Raynos: When there are duplicates. Copy/paste this into the console both ways on this page. :) *(Or when there was no hash, but I assume you knew that one.)*

Comment: thank you, this worked like a charm. And thanks for the indexOf reference too. Extremely helpful since i keep trying to have everything work back to ie6

Comment: @patrick dw: is there also a way to simultaneously obtain the title attribute for each such anchor? ideally, push it to the second dimension of the hashes array?

Comment: PS figured out how to push it into a separate array, so I know the workaround, but would still appreciate if it is possible to use push for multidimensional arrays

Comment: @unomyname: Sure, you just create a new Array that contains both inside the `.push()`. Like this `.push( [ elems[i].title, elems[i].name ] );`

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want a list of anchors rather than a list of the links to the anchors? Use the `a[name],a[id]:not([href])` selector to find all anchor elements with a name, or an id but no href.

```
$('a[name],a[id]:not([href])').each(function(i,e){
  var name = $(e).attr('name') | $(e).attr('id');
  $('<option/>', { value: '#'+name, text: e.text() }).appendTo('#TheSelect');
});
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple function to return the array you want. No need for jQuery.

```
function linksArray(){
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a"), linklist = [];
    for(var i=0, len=links.length; i<len; ++i){
        linklist.push(links[i].attributes.getNamedItem("href").value);
    }
    return linklist;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

jQuery makes this pretty easy:

```
$("a").filter( function() {
    return $(this).attr("href")[0] == "#";
} ).each( function() {
    $("select").append("<option>" + $(this).attr("href") + "</option>");
} );
```

That just adds the text of the "href" field as the text of the "option" flag to every "select" field on the page. Obviously you'd need to tailor it to suit your needs, but that should get you started.

Comment: Using `[0]` to get the first character of a string doesn't work in earlier versions of IE. Use the `charAt` method instead.

Comment: When did the question mention jQuery?

Comment: @Raynos, when did the question mention that you couldn't use jQuery? jQuery is a JavaScript library and was designed to make tasks such as this easier. The author of the question would do good to learn how to use it effectively.

Comment: @Stargazer712 The author of the question would do good to learn how to use _the DOM_ effectively. Don't promote hacking with abstractions you don't understand. Also if we're going to use a DOM library I would recommend he chooses a good not, not just go with the generic popular jQuery library. This is the same as recommending someone use the Boost library when they ask a question about C.

Comment: @Raynos, I could make the same argument about any library in any language. Don't shy away from useful abstractions.

Comment: @Raynos, and Boost is for C++...not C. Recommending that would be kindof a dumb thing to do.

Comment: Don't promote using abstractions without understanding how they work. jQuery is not a useful abstraction, it's merely a popular one.

Comment: @Raynos, you have "Not Invented Here" syndrome. Learn to relax. Be more productive.

Comment: This code is painfully slow, an abuse of the document object model, and not cross-browser friendly.